# why I cannot add a object to firebase storage in android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a object of user into firebase storage. this is my User class

```
        data class Usr(
        var id: String = "",
        var emailText:String="",
        var imageProfile:String=""
    )
    
    {
    constructor():this("","","")
    
    }
   /// ///////////////////////////////////////
   val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid)
   val user = Usr(uid, email.text.toString(), "")
   ref.setValue(user).addOnSuccessListener {
                  Log.d("TAG", "Finally we saved the user to Firebase Database")
                  val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                  intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                  startActivity(intent)
        
               }
               .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Failed to set value to database: ${it.message}")
               }
```

but notthing happened. what did I miss?

Comment: Does this line `Log.d("TAG", "Failed to set value to database: ${it.message}")` print something?

Comment: nothing happened!!

Comment: Of course nothing happened. You MUST implements **Serializable** and specify the **getter** method of the member variable in the **Usr** class. The serialization procedure only care about *getter* and *setter* method, not the member variables.